# Sum of values for all accounts using the most recent date for each

Tags: mysql, sql

Accounts are worth different values over time.  I want to know what is the value of all accounts at the most recent date for which the account has data.

```
Account      Date     Value
Account 1    1/1/19   12
Account 1    1/3/19   32
Account 1    1/12/19  52
Account 2    4/1/18   123
Account 2    4/22/18  42
Account 3    2/1/19   11
Account 3    7/1/18   64
Account 3    8/12/18  74
```

For this data set, I want my end result to be 105 because 52+42+11 are the values on the most recent date for each account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are multiple ways of doing it, my preferable way is to do self-join, like this:

```
select Account, Date, Value
from accounts as a inner join (
    select Account, max(Date) as maxDate
    from accounts
    group by Account
) as t on a.Account = t.Account and a.Date = t.maxDate
```

Comment: This gives me the value for each account.  Do I then need a separate operation to sum the values on the new table?

Comment: if you need sum across all - just replace `select Account, Date, Value` with `select sum(Value)`

Answer (score 1):

First group by account to get the max date of each account and then join to the table:

```
select sum(t.value) totalvalue
from tablename t inner join (
  select account, max(date) date
  from tablename
  group by account
) g on g.account = t.account and g.date = t.date
```

You can also do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select sum(t.value) totalvalue
from tablename t 
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where account = t.account and date > t.date
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=69ff6ab56fc97020447b402082287b39).
Result:

```
> | totalvalue |
> | ---------: |
> |        105 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to sum up values for those rows where the date is the maximum date for the account:

```
select sum(value)
from mytable
where (account, date) in (select account, max(date) from mytable group by account);
```

As of MySQL 8 you should be able to use a window function to avoid reading the table twice:

```
select sum(value)
from
(
  select value, date = max(date) over (partition by account) as is_latest_for_account
  from mytable
)
where is_latest_for_account;
```

Comment: I think this is it!

Comment: @Justin Kelley: Thanks. I've added an alternative for newer MySQL versions that may (or may not) run faster.

Answer (score 0):

do something like

```
select max(date), account
from table
group by account
```

this should give you the latest date associated to each account. then, you can create a CTE and join back to it by account & date. something like this.

```
with q as (
  select max(date), account
  from table
  group by account
) select t1.account, t1.date, t1.value  
  from table t1 
  join q on t1.account = q.account and t1.date = q.date
```

Comment: just note cte (`with ...`) are only supported by some versions of mysql, so its better to mention it

Comment: A CTE can be replicated | mimic on other SQL version in many ways, like the answers given here already.

Comment: I've formatted the code for you. (It's easily done with the `{}` button.)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a correlated subquery for this:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where a.date = (select max(a2.date)
                from accounts a2
                where a2.account = a.account
               );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `accounts(account, date)`.